# Rendering three types of events as HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have to clean up some Javascript and I am trying to figure out a more elegant way to write this code below. It's basically looping through 3 dictionaries with the same loop structure and appending some custom HTML onto a specific `div`.  I wanted to see if there is a way to avoid this repetitive code:

```
if (dtInt in calendarEventDict) {
    var arrEvents = calendarEventDict[dtInt];
    for (var a = 0; a < arrEvents.length; a++) {
        var calendarEvent = arrEvents[a];
        $("#dateCupcake" + i).append("<div  dateId='" + calendarEvent.Date + "' class='event " + "cal" + calendarEvent.CalendarId + " " + calendarEvent.CalendarClassName + "' calendarId='" + calendarEvent.CalendarId + "' eventDateId='" + calendarEvent.Id + "' id='" + calendarEvent.EventId + "'>" + calendarEvent.DisplayName + "</div>");
    }
}
if (dtInt in vacationEvents) {
    var arrEventsV = vacationEvents[dtInt];
    for (var v = 0; v < arrEventsV.length; v++) {
        var vacationEvent = arrEventsV[v];
        $("#dateCupcake" + i).append("<div  dateId='" + vacationEvent.Date + "' class='event " + "cal1 blueAllDay' calendarId='1' eventDateId='" + vacationEvent.Id + "' id='" + vacationEvent.EventId + "'><img src='/Content/Images/Icons/pawn_glass_" + vacationEvent.ApprovalIcon + ".png' />" + vacationEvent.PersonName + "</div>");
    }
}
if (dtInt in travelEvents) {
    var arrEventsV1 = travelEvents[dtInt];
    for (var v1 = 0; v1 < arrEventsV1.length; v1++) {
        var travelEvent = arrEventsV1[v1];
        $("#dateCupcake" + i).append("<div  calendarId='2' dateId='" + travelEvent.Date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy") + "' class='event " + "cal2" + " blueAllDay' calendarId='2' eventDateId='" + travelEvent.Id + "' eventId='" + travelEvent.TravelRequest.Id + "'><img src='/Content/Images/Icons/user1_earth16.png' />" + travelEvent.TravelRequest.Person.LastName + ", " + travelEvent.TravelRequest.Person.FirstName.Substring(0, 1) + " visiting " + travelEvent.TravelRequest.TechnicalCentre.Name + "</div> ");
    }
}
```

Comment: HTML String concatenation is evil.

Comment: @Raynos - what would you suggest as an alternative

Comment: Construct objects using the DOM

Comment: @Raynos I agree the DOM way is better but assuming there are only a few items here its not a big deal. Simpler to let jQuery handle it.

Comment: @leora what is `i` in `$("#dateCupcake" + i)` ?

Comment: @JamesKhoury it's a big deal if he has a 500 char long string literal. I hate vertical scrolling. That needs to be fixed to either use a templating engine or the DOM

Comment: @Raynos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112158/javascript-string-concatenation would suggest its probably not as big a deal as we all think.

Comment: @JamesKhoury we're not talking about performance differences. Were talking about the DOM aint no bloody string. Stop writing HTML in my javascript.

Comment: @Raynos I think you'd have to back up that opinion before others will take that seriously. In this case i think it would be overkill.

Comment: @JamesKhoury seriously :\. People don't understand that HTML in your javascript is completely backwards? The DOM is a living document, if people want to rip it to shreds and build it back up again with their strings then they should go do that behind closed doors. A page is a tree of nodes, if you want to manipulate it then manipulate it with nodes. There's absolutely no point in building nodes up using HTML strings, then invoking a HTML parser to build nodes when you can build nodes directly.

Comment: @Raynos I think you missed my point. While I may agree with you on the idea, in practical terms it is often unnecessary.

Comment: @JamesKhoury It is neccessary, the above code is horribly unreadable and horribly unmaintainable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1966/discussion-between-james-khoury-and-raynos)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest refactor would be to simply pull out the common functionality, and pass in the array for each case, as well as a function used to create your div content from the current item in the loop.  Assuming dtInt is global:

```
function checkDtInt(arr, funcToCreateDiv) {    
    if (dtInt in arr) {
        var arrEventsV1 = arr[dtInt];
        for (var v1 = 0; v1 < arrEventsV1.length; v1++) {
            var travelEvent = arrEventsV1[v1];
            $("#dateCupcake" + i).append(funcToCreateDiv(travelEvent));
        }
    }
 }

checkDtInt(calendarEventDict, function(item) { 
   return "<div  dateId='" + item.Date + "' class='event " + "cal" + item.CalendarId + " " + item.CalendarClassName + "' calendarId='" + item.CalendarId + "' eventDateId='" + item.Id + "' id='" + item.EventId + "'>" + item.DisplayName + "</div>"
});

checkDtInt(vacationEvents, function(item) { 
   return "<div  dateId='" + item.Date + "' class='event " + "cal1 blueAllDay' calendarId='1' eventDateId='" + item.Id + "' id='" + item.EventId + "'><img src='/Content/Images/Icons/pawn_glass_" + item.ApprovalIcon + ".png' />" + item.PersonName + "</div>"
});

checkDtInt(travelEvents, function(item) { 
   return "<div  calendarId='2' dateId='" + item.Date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy") + "' class='event " + "cal2" + " blueAllDay' calendarId='2' eventDateId='" + item.Id + "' eventId='" + item.TravelRequest.Id + "'><img src='/Content/Images/Icons/user1_earth16.png' />" + item.TravelRequest.Person.LastName + ", " + item.TravelRequest.Person.FirstName.Substring(0, 1) + " visiting " + item.TravelRequest.TechnicalCentre.Name + "</div> "
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This is Less code but I wouldn't say simpler:</strike>
EDIT: Its not even less code any more. Less repeated code though.

```
var groups =[
    {
        events: calenderEventDict,

        calendaridfn: function(){ return this.calendarId;},
        contentsfn: function(){ return this.DisplayName; },
        datefn: function(){ return this.Date;}
    },
    {
        events: vacationEvents,

        calendaridfn: function(){ return "1";},
        contentsfn: function(){
            var contents = jQuery("<img/>")
                .prop("src", "/Content/Images/Icons/pawn_glass_" +  this.ApprovalIcon + ".png")
                .after(this.PersonName);
            return contents;
        },
        datefn: function(){ return this.Date;}
    },
    {
        events: travelEvents,

        calendaridfn: function(){ return "2";},
        contentsfn: function(){ 
            var contents= jQuery("<img />")
                .prop("src", '/Content/Images/Icons/user1_earth16.png')
                .after(
                    this.TravelRequest.Person.LastName + ", " +
                    this.TravelRequest.Person.FirstName.Substring(0, 1) + 
                    " visiting " +
                    this.TravelRequest.TechnicalCentre.Name
                );
             return contents;
        },
        datefn: function(){ return this.Date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"); }
    }
];

jQuery.each(groups, function(){
    if (dtInt in this.events) 
    {
        var group = this;
        jQuery.each(events, function(){
            var calendarId = group.calendaridfn.call(this);
            $("#dateCupcake" + i).append(
                jQuery("<div/>").prop({
                    dateId: group.datefn.call(this),
                    class: ["event",
                            "cal" + calendarId,
                            (this.CalendarClassName || "blueAllDay")].join(" "),
                    calendarId: calendarId,
                    eventDateId: this.Id, 
                    id: this.EventId 
                })
                .append(group.contentsfn.call(this))
            );
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT:-** So after a discussion with Raynos I've come to the understanding that its better to not have a huge html string over the object creation method. I've edited my answer to reflect this idea.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways of doing this. But no need to over complicate things, your code isn't bad at all. Could use some optimisation though, that's all.

1. So let's start by optimizing your code. You can get faster results in slower machines with a small simple refactoring. That's also clean.
   I presume that you don't need tp declare new variables for each of the loops. Meaning you can use the same ones.
2. Not always a standard, but good practice. To use 'single Quotes' and keep the "double quotes for HTML" when possible

   ```
   // have all you need here, only once. These variables can be used for more than one loop.
   var events,
       eventsLen,
       travelRequest,
       ev,
       i;

   if (dtInt in calendarEventDict) {
       events = calendarEventDict[dtInt];
       i = arrEvents.length;

       // loop until we reach 0. Less calls, less checks ;)
       while(--i) {
           ev = arrEvents[a];
           $("#dateCupcake" + i).append("<div  dateId='" + ev.Date + "' class='event " + "cal" + ev.CalendarId + " " + ev.CalendarClassName + "' calendarId='" + ev.CalendarId + "' eventDateId='" + ev.Id + "' id='" + ev.EventId + "'>" + ev.DisplayName + "</div>");
       }
   }
   if (dtInt in vacationEvents) {
       events = vacationEvents[dtInt];
       i = arrEventsV.length;

       while(--i) {
           ev = arrEventsV[v];
           $("#dateCupcake" + i).append("<div  dateId='" + ev.Date + "' class='event " + "cal1 blueAllDay' calendarId='1' eventDateId='" + ev.Id + "' id='" + ev.EventId + "'><img src='/Content/Images/Icons/pawn_glass_" + ev.ApprovalIcon + ".png' />" + ev.PersonName + "</div>");
       }
   }
   if (dtInt in travelEvents) {
       events = travelEvents[dtInt];
       i = arrEventsV1.length;

       while(--i) {
           ev = arrEventsV1[v1];
           travelRequest = ev.TravelRequest;
           $("#dateCupcake" + i).append("<div  calendarId='2' dateId='" + ev.Date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy") + "' class='event " + "cal2" + " blueAllDay' calendarId='2' eventDateId='" + ev.Id + "' eventId='" + travelRequest.Id + "'><img src='/Content/Images/Icons/user1_earth16.png' />" + travelRequest.Person.LastName + ", " + travelRequest.Person.FirstName.Substring(0, 1) + " visiting " + travelRequest.TechnicalCentre.Name + "</div> ");
       }
   }
   ```